# trouble with ObjectInputStream, returning a wrong value

Tags: java

I have this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to domein.Auto
```

The value I get is this:

```
[[nummerplaat= 123xyz, merk= Toyota, model = Yaris, nummerplaat= 456abc, merk= Opel, model = Astra, nummerplaat= azerty, merk= BMW, model = Berline, nummerplaat= qwerty, merk= Toyota, model = Avensis, nummerplaat= 789cde, merk= Mercedes, model = C-klasse Berline, nummerplaat= 567xyz, merk= Renault, model = Fluence, nummerplaat= ab12ab, merk= Opel, model = Zafira, nummerplaat= xy12xy, merk= Peugeot, model = 308]]
```

However this should be:

```
[nummerplaat= 123xyz, merk= Toyota, model = Yaris, nummerplaat= 456abc, merk= Opel, model = Astra, nummerplaat= azerty, merk= BMW, model = Berline, nummerplaat= qwerty, merk= Toyota, model = Avensis, nummerplaat= 789cde, merk= Mercedes, model = C-klasse Berline, nummerplaat= 567xyz, merk= Renault, model = Fluence, nummerplaat= ab12ab, merk= Opel, model = Zafira, nummerplaat= xy12xy, merk= Peugeot, model = 308]
```

The code I'm using is the following:

```
public class ObjectStreamManipulaties {

    public <E> List<E> geefObjecten(File naamBestand) {
        List<E> li = new ArrayList<>();

        try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(naamBestand))) {
            while (true) {
                li.add((E) ois.readObject());
            }
        } catch (EOFException e) {
//EOF bereikt, continue
            return li;
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ObjectStreamManipulaties.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I use this method in the following mapper class:

```
package persistentie;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import domein.Auto;
import java.io.File;

public class AutoMapper {

    private File naamBestand;

    public AutoMapper(File bestand){
        this.naamBestand = bestand;
    }

    public List<Auto> geefAutos() {

        System.out.println(new ObjectStreamManipulaties().geefObjecten(naamBestand));
        return new ObjectStreamManipulaties().geefObjecten(naamBestand);
    }
}
```

If I manually put in the the list like this, everything works:

```
public List<Auto> geefAutos() {
      List<Auto> lijstAutos = new ArrayList<Auto>();
      lijstAutos.add(new Auto("123xyz", "Toyota", "Yaris"));
      lijstAutos.add(new Auto("456abc", "Opel", "Astra"));
      lijstAutos.add(new Auto("azerty", "BMW", "Berline"));
      lijstAutos.add(new Auto("qwerty", "Toyota", "Avensis"));
      lijstAutos.add(new Auto("789cde", "Mercedes", "C-klasse Berline"));
      lijstAutos.add(new Auto("567xyz", "Renault", "Fluence"));
      lijstAutos.add(new Auto("ab12ab", "Opel", "Zafira"));
      lijstAutos.add(new Auto("xy12xy", "Peugeot", "308"));
      return lijstAutos;

    }
```

It is the value from "li" that is wrong. What is wrong in the code?

Comment: Which line in this code throws the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be reading the whole list from your file, but assuming that it has individual elements in it. 
Instead of your `while(true)` loop, just do `li = (List<E>) ois.readObject();`

Comment: this works for my error, but then when I use the method on another file, it gives another error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: domein.Onderhoud cannot be cast to java.util.List

Comment: So, the other file has different contents :) The code that reads the data must match the code, that has written it. If you have saved the List, you have to be reading back the List, and if you were saving individual cars, you have to read them back one by one. If you have to, you could make both ways work with something like this: `Object o = ois.readObject(); if(o instanceof List) { return (List<E>) o } else do  { li.add((E) o); o = try { ois.readObject(); } catch(EOFException e) { break; } } while(true);`

Comment: Hi, yeah I resolved it with 2 different methods, where 1 is the solution you gave. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Without the output (when you save the file) code i can't help you; However try to input/output the entire list object instead of save element by element, is much more simpler.

Comment: I don't know what you mean, i dont save my file, i just read from it.